# R gzfile output is incomplete

Tags: r

I am trying to get gz output from a data.frame in R.
I used the following script:

```
write.table(res,file = gzfile(newfile,open="wb"),quote = FALSE,sep="\t",row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE)
```

But the output is incomplete.
However if I don't use gzfile(), the output is ok. For example:

```
write.table(res,file =newfile,quote = FALSE,sep="\t",row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE)
```

The output is not big, just 9 MB in gz form.I don't find the reason on internet.I wonder why this could happern.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a connection and opening it, but you never close it.  It won't be complete until closed.

There are two solutions:

Don't open the connection, let `write.table` open it:

```
write.table(res,file = gzfile(newfile),quote = FALSE,sep="\t",row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE)
```

Or, save it in a variable, and close it explicitly:

```
con <- gzfile(newfile, "wb")
write.table(res,file = con,quote = FALSE,sep="\t",row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE)
close(con)
```